# Efficiency issue when rendering custom aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, performance

We have a custom aura component (see picture) which has to show a list of records from a custom object where the user can select other other records (from other custom objects) which will be associated with the primary one.

[image: Picture 1]

Lookups are used to obtain this information. I am currently facing performance issues as I have used `lightning:editForm` inside an `aura:iteration` and have to render over 100+ records. Unfortunately I am not sure how else to achieve a similar result with good performance.

Any suggestions how to improve efficiency are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi mr.kukulis, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). At a minimum, you might want to include some sample code to show us how your component works. Otherwise, I don't know that you're likely to get much input on your question.

Answer (score 0):

lightning:editForm is a very "heavy" component and not meant to be used in bulk. Use a custom component/template for each row and use a custom lookup component, such as [Lightning Strike Lookup](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup), or even write your own specialized version. You should be able to get much better performance this way.